# Jquery move x to y and disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got these 3 elements with buttons, I need an element moves to the target (X) and disappear,with the  click. Second tip, how I can make move ONLY the div pressed? Now all the divs takes the animation.

Hi wrote this codepen, and my elements just takes the property of opacity but I can't move it.

Important: all the elements should reach the target X, even the second and the third.

**[Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VaajWz)**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("div").animate({
            left: '250px',
            opacity: '0.5'
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.try {
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.target {
  font-size: 50px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="target"> X</div>

<div  class="try"><button id="play">Start Animation</button></div>
<div  class="try"><button id="play">Start Animation</button></div>
<div  class="try"><button id="play">Start Animation</button></div>
```

Comment: An element needs position, other than `static`, to be able to have a `left` and `top` value set. Also, ID's are unique.

Comment: Your question is confusing. You ask how to make only the clicked div move, but then at the end want all of them to move? Can you clarify the type of behavior you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Updated codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwwGbN)**

That can be done by adding `position:absolute` to the divs :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    var current_div = $(this).closest(".try");

    current_div.animate({
      left: '85%',
      opacity: '0.5',
      top: '0px',
      margin: '0px'
    }, 2000, function(){ 
      current_div.hide();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.try {
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

.target {
  font-size: 50px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="target"> X</div>

<div class="try"><button id="play">Start Animation</button></div>
<div class="try" style="margin-top:105px"><button id="play">Start Animation</button></div>
<div class="try" style="margin-top:210px"><button id="play">Start Animation</button></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the functionality you are looking for by getting position of the `X` element, changing the css of the element you'd like to move to `absolute` positioning (`.try`), then setting the opacity in the callback of jQuery's animate:

```js
$('.play').on('click', function() {
  var clickedButton = $(this),
    parentDiv = $(this).parent('.try'),
    targetPosition = $('.target').position(),
    targetLeft = targetPosition.left,
    targetTop = targetPosition.top;

  $(parentDiv).css({
      "position": "absolute"
    })
    .animate({
      left: targetLeft,
      top: targetTop
    }, 1000, "linear", function() {
      $(this).css({
        "opacity": "0.5"
      });
    });

});
```

```css
.try {
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.target {
  font-size: 50px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="target">X</div>

<div class="try">
  <button class="play">Start Animation</button>
</div>
<div class="try">
  <button class="play">Start Animation</button>
</div>
<div class="try">
  <button class="play">Start Animation</button>
</div>
```

Finally, you don't want to use multiple instances of the same `id` so just change `#play` to `.play`:

```
<div class="target"> X</div>

<div  class="try"><button class="play">Start Animation</button></div>
<div  class="try"><button class="play">Start Animation</button></div>
<div  class="try"><button class="play">Start Animation</button></div>
```